# What is wrong with my mental model?

Tags: c++

Why does this work...

```
string str("special_string");
string arr[10];
arr[0] = str;
```

while this causes a seg-fault?

```
string str("special_string");
string *buf = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string) * 10);
buf[0] = str; /* or *buf = str; */
```

Aren't both instances a by-value copy?

Comment: You shouldn't use malloc with `string`.

Comment: Maybe my question didn't hint at my actual intent, which was to create a heap allocated array of strings.

Comment: @c_dubs Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Comment: Ordinarily I would, but I'm implementing a parallel merge sort, and the overhead of accessing vector elements seems to increase running time by a factor of about two.  My implementation is templated, and worked for fundamental types, but suddenly failed when I tried using it for objects.  Now I know why lol.

Answer (score 0):

> while this causes a seg-fault?

because you have a problem here:

```
string *buf = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string));
```

you only allocate memory but do not initialize object of type `std::string` properly as `malloc()` does not call ctor. If you use `operator new` instead you code would work:

```
string str("special_string");
string *buf = new string;
*buf = str;
```

and of course you should use `delete` instead of `free()` when you will need to destroy that object.

Comment: I'm trying to create a heap allocated array of strings (I know my original question didn't really hint at this intent).

Comment: Okay, I get it now.  It's not a by-value copy, it's invoking the copy constructor for string, causing a seg-fault when it tries to interpret the uninitialized memory as a string and access its data buffer.

Comment: @c_dubs no it is invoking assignment operator (which may invoke copy ctor, but most probably would not), but yes it crashes because object is uninitialized